# How to reach a constant outside of the function in React function component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, function, react-hooks

When I try to reach the `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth` outside of the function I get the error which I added below. How can I fix it?

```
function WH() {
    
        const onImgLoad = ({ target: x }) => {
          const { offsetHeight, offsetWidth } = x;
          console.log(offsetHeight, offsetWidth);
        };
    
        return (
          <div>
            <img
              onLoad={onImgLoad}
              alt=""
              src={dragUrl.current}
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    
      console.log("height",offsetHeight)
      console.log("width", offsetWidth)
```

[image: Error]

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to try to access the values outside of the component entirely.  What is the goal of this?

Comment: One problem is that the variables aren't declared in the scope where your console.log operates.  Second problem is that the callback function you defined as onImageLoad will not have executed when the console.logs run.  So you'll get undefined even if you declare the vars in the right spot.

Comment: @David I'll use them in another function to create a stage by using KonvaJS

Comment: @James How can I write it properly?

Comment: @apotamkinn: What "other function"?  You mean in another component?  If that's the case then they'd need to be kept in state somewhere.  (An ancestor component, a context, Redux or something similar...)  It's not really clear what the goal is here.

Comment: It's not clear what purpose console.log outside of the onImageLoad function is serving.  You already have a console.log inside, which should work properly.

Comment: @David Yes, in another component. I uploaded files from local and I select the files and create an image from them. I want to use the properties of the image while creating a stage and I will create that stage in another component. That's why I need to reach width and height of the image from this WH functional component.

Comment: @James I wanted to see if width and height is usable outside of the function and it is not as you can see. That is the question actually.

Comment: @apotamkinn: Then your next step is to go back to some React tutorials and learn about state management.  You're trying to use global variables, which is going to cause more problems than it solves.  Store your values in state, potentially relying on `useContext` or a state management system like Redux.  Then components can access those state values.

Comment: @David Thank you I'll check

Comment: I agree with @David.  IMO the offsetHeight/widths should be stored in state variables (in the onImageLoad function), add a useEffect which triggers when they are updated, and there you can put your code that makes use of those values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the properties in the component, I suggest putting them in the state.

```
function WH() {
    const [offsetHeight, setOffSetHeight] = useState()
    const [offsetWidth, setOffSetWidth] = useState()

    const onImgLoad = ({ target }) => {
        setOffSetHeight(target.offsetHeight)
        setOffSetWidth(target.offsetWidth)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <img onLoad={onImgLoad} alt="" src={dragUrl.current} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Alternatively, you could create local variables in the component.

```
function WH() {
    let offsetHeight
    let offsetWidth

    const onImgLoad = ({ target }) => {
        offsetHeight = target.offsetHeight
        offsetWidth = target.offsetWidth
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <img onLoad={onImgLoad} alt="" src={dragUrl.current} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I tried both solutions but still can not reach offsetHeight and offsetWidth outside of the WH function

Comment: Could it be that you receive "undefined" when logging the value?

Perhaps it is not because you can't reach it, but rather because the value does not exist on `target` therefore, you are replacing the initial value of undefined with undefined.